# One to one bidirectional Hibernate mapping using SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have `Questionnaie_Details` table which has a unique id as shown below

```
@Table(name="QuestionnaireDetails")
@Id
@Column(name="Questionnaire_ID", nullable = "false")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long Questionnaire_Id;
```

I also have `Questionnaie_Review` table which has its unique ID (primary key) as well as `Questionnaire_Id`, which is a foreign key.

```
@Table(name="QuestionnaireReview")
@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Long ID;

@OnetoOne
@JoinColumn(name="QuestionnaireId")
private QuestionnaireDetailsEntity questionnaireDetailsEntity
```

Can someone please tell me if this is correct mapping? I get an error that `QuestionnaireReview`'s `ID` is null, I thought the DB should be generating this automatically?

Comment: The code wouldn't compile, so it's not correct mapping, no. And even if it compiles, we can't know if it's correct because we don't know the actual desired cardinality for the association. If you want help about an error, you need to show the complete and exact stack trace of the error, as wel as the code causing the exception.

Comment: Is the underscore in the table name? If yes it won't match. `Questionnaire_Review != QuestionnaireReview`.

Comment: Or maybe it depends on what SQL server you use, dunno.

Comment: @MouseEvent yes pardon me, just disregard the underscore in both cases.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please tell me what other information you require me to post. This is part of work code which I am unable to show for privacy reasons, that is why I posted minimal code just to ask what is the correct way of defining the association.

Comment: I said: *If you want help about an error, you need to show the complete and exact stack trace of the error, as well as the code causing the exception.*.